# Reducing an lvmgroup - cannot resize to xxxx extents as later ones are allocated

Tags: centos, lvm, gparted, pvmove

I've been going through the process of reducing the size of a Centos 6.10 image by reducing an lvmgroup.  I'm at the point where I've been able to run this command:

```
pvresize -tv --setphysicalvolumesize  1600G /dev/md125p2
```

And it's giving me the following error message:

```
 /dev/md125p2: cannot resize to 409599 extents as later ones are allocated.
```

I'm trying to understand how to construct the pvmove  command to get  rid of the error, but I don't quite  get the concept.

Here is the output of this command  `pvs -v --segments /dev/md125p`

```
  PV           VG            Fmt  Attr PSize PFree   Start  SSize  LV       Start Type   PE Ranges                 
  /dev/md125p2 vg_centos6svr lvm2 a--u 1.86t 320.11g      0 384000 lv_mysql     0 linear /dev/md125p2:0-383999     
  /dev/md125p2 vg_centos6svr lvm2 a--u 1.86t 320.11g 384000  81947              0 free                             
  /dev/md125p2 vg_centos6svr lvm2 a--u 1.86t 320.11g 465947  12800 lv_root      0 linear /dev/md125p2:465947-478746
  /dev/md125p2 vg_centos6svr lvm2 a--u 1.86t 320.11g 478747   1998 lv_swap      0 linear /dev/md125p2:478747-480744
  /dev/md125p2 vg_centos6svr lvm2 a--u 1.86t 320.11g 480745   7500 lv_home      0 linear /dev/md125p2:480745-488244
```

I know the move command has to look something like this:

```
pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/md125p2 vg_centos6svr:yyyy-end
```

I'm just not clear how to calculate the yyyy-end part. I figure  it means move that 81947 (blocks?) that start at 384000, but what is "yyyy" and "end"?

Comment: In comments you say the size is not smaller after doing pvmoves. Please you edit your question to add another  `pvs -v --segments`  plus the size of the array, perhaps from  `mdadm --detail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I can see is everything is on `/dev/md125p2` and we want to reduce the size of this PV.

Your output from `pvs -v --segments /dev/md125p` show you have a very large free space (`SSize==81947`) after your `lv_mysql` and before your `lv_root`.  This is big enough to house `lv_root` and *all* of the LVs that come after it in the physical layout.

So, the first set of numbers I'd suggest is:

```
***# pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/md125p2:480745-488244 /dev/md125p2:384000+7499
```

that is, move the whole of `lv_home` to the free space starting directly after `lv_mysql`.

Then re-run `pvs -v --segments /dev/md125p` to see the revised numbers, and move the next block into whatever free space is left.

This will effectively defrag your PV.

Now, `pvmove` may have *way* more options than what I'm using (maybe specifying the PV instead of the extents?) but what I got comfortable with is just being explicit with the blocks, so all of my sources and targets are in the form of `/dev/<dev>:<Start>-<End>` or `/dev/<dev>:<Start>+<SSize-1>`.

I suspect your problem was mainly missing the extents off of your "source" specification.

I've seen a few examples out their using `-end` - I don't know if that's something that's *supposed* to work, but it would beg the question "end of *what*?". So I avoid it and use explicit block numbers.  You just need to be mindful that the `+` syntax is a **plus**, and needs to be one less than the SSize.

### Extra

OK, on the source side it seems like you can do `-name lv_home /dev/md125p2` as a short-hand for `/dev/md125p2:480745-488244` - but note also that this will get more complex if `lh_home` was fragmented into multiple extents (would it mean "all fragments?") - I think I still prefer the numbers approach.  Note that your example in the question *didn't* include the LV name, so I'm not sure what `pvmove` would have understood from what you gave it...

Comment: Worked! Unfortunately, the actual disk size stays the same (i'm trying to reduce the physical image size for Clonezilla). If you have any idea about this, let me know. Raid 0 configuration.

Comment: @JackBeNimble You still need a `pvresize` at the end of all the defraging!  Also, recent clonezilla's will penetrate the whole LVM process and record the image of the LVs - if you take a partition approach to saving the image.  I think that is way safer than imaging the underlying PVs.  It also seems to be file system aware, and therefore only saves the blocks being used.  I'd recommend `pigz` compression on top.  Maybe a new question for this?  I actually suspect that you didn't need any of the defraggging for clonezilla!

Comment: dsz - the issue is we have is an old clonezilla image that is no longer fitting onto the SSDs because they are 50 GB apiece smaller. I got around it by shrinking the image w/ the above exercise, then restoring w/ an option to ignore source disk size. Then it worked. Thanks for getting me on the right track with the pvmove.

Comment: can you check this question? https://serverfault.com/questions/1074461/centos-6-10-how-to-increase-allocated-pe-size-to-take-up-free-p-e-size

Answer (score 1):

Reducing a PV requires moving extents to free space before the desired size. In your case extents below 409599.

First, test a backup restore to be sure data can be recovered if necessary.

`lvremove` volumes you do not need.

`pvmove` allows specifying extents by LV name, and the destination by offsets with the + notation. When providing the destination, that must be a PV, not a VG.

Move one LV to the first extent in free space. The offset is the size of the segment being moved.

```
pvmove --alloc anywhere  -n lv_swap /dev/md125p2 /dev/md125p2:384000+1998
```

Get the new segment layout with `pvs -v --segments` again. Repeat the `pvmove` with a different LV and the new free space start extent.

Personally, I prefer data VGs separate from operating system VGs. But this is your storage, lay it out as you wish.