# Centos 6.10 - How to increase allocated PE size to take up Free P/E size

Tags: centos6, lvm, pvmove

I recently had to shrink  a Clonezilla image, but overdid it an now have to recover some unused free space.

Here is the output of vgadisplay:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_centos6svr
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  27
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               1.78 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              466366
  Alloc PE / Size       406298 / 1.55 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       60068 / 234.64 GiB
  VG UUID
```

I need to expand the Allocated PE/Size to include the Free PE size.

This is the partial output of lvdisplay:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_centos6svr/lv_mysql
  LV Name                lv_mysql
  VG Name                vg_centos6svr
  LV UUID                VwpGH0-DLnA-Ouf0-StWs-us8Y-rDwk-GLL2A9
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time Centos6svr, 2018-09-28 07:31:11 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.46 TiB
  Current LE             384000
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     1024
  Block device           253:2
```

This is the one I need to expand to include the re-allocated space.

/dev/vg_centos6svr/lv_mysql

What's the process here? Just increase /dev/vg_centos6svr/lv_mysql? What is the command - pvresize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing the Physical Volumes (PVs) and Logical Volumes (LVs).

If you're restoring a Clonezilla *partition* image, then you need a LV partition big enough to receive it.

So that would be an `lvresize`.  You'll be able to expand the LV into all of the free space on all of the PVs in your Volume Group (VG).

LVs are allocated from VGs; VGs get their storage from PVs.

Harking back to a previous question of yours, this didn't need any "defraging" of the PV, as LVs can grow across fragmented extents - that's one of the main points of LVM - the allocation of LVs doesn't have to be contiguous, or even all on the same PV.

Comment: Thanks - the lvmresize with the --resizefs worked like a charm. Btw, do you know anything about RAID? I have an inactive RAID array somehow that I'd like to get rid of. Please check https://serverfault.com/questions/1074559/how-to-delete-an-inactive-raid-array-centos-6.