# LVM logical volume for /home partition corrupted after lvresize to increase swap space Fedora 25

Tags: lvm, fedora, swap

I added 6GB of memory on an older Dell PowerEdge 1850 that we use just for backups to an attached hardware RAID from Promise Technology called a VessRAID connected by iSCSI. After a few weeks I noticed the swap space was only 2 GB and decided to resize the home partition and add 6GB to swap.

I followed the steps to [Extend Swap on an LVM2 Logical Volume](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-swap-adding.html). On reboot I got to emergency mode and the dreaded and "`Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!`". I also see `failed to find cpu0 device node` error. The server is on the 4.9.3 kernel. Is my best bet still to try mke2fs with or without the -S option as [suggested here](https://serverfault.com/questions/433275/lvm-logical-volume-partition-corrupted-after-lvreduce)? I also tried the resize2fs command but I get "`Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdb`"

Not sure if it's related but here are some other errors I was seeing in the logs before reboot:

```
Jan 19 20:06:00 curie systemd-logind: Removed session 156.
Jan 19 20:14:56 curie systemd: Failed to set up mount unit: Device or resource busy
Jan 19 21:10:18 curie systemd: local-fs.target: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit home.mount is masked.
Jan 19 21:11:14 curie systemd: local-fs.target: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

`/etc/fstab` has this:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=e3507fa1-f9ee-4951-8ecc-48f16183dee9 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: You wrote :"decided to resize the home partition and add 6GB to swap" What did you do to resize your home partition? To shrink a partition you have to shrink the filesystem first and the partition later.

Comment: So you would have to:         1. (as root user) umount /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home /home    2. fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home /home                                  3. resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home /home NEW_SIZE               4. lvresize -L NEW_SIZE /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home /home

Comment: try vgcfgrestore to restore your home volume from /etc/lvm/archive

Comment: But I already did the resize using these commands from the Fedora link:

`Disable swapping for the associated logical volume:
swapoff -v /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap swap

Resize the LVM2 logical volume by 6GB:
lvresize /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home -L -6GB
lvresize /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap -L +6GB
Format the new swap space:
mkswap /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap
Enable the extended logical volume:
swapon -v /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap swap`

Comment: The instructions you linked show how to _expand_ a logical volume, not how to _shrink_ one. You have destroyed your filesystem. Now you have to restore from backup.

Comment: The title of the link says Extend Swap. In the other link I have there's a mention of mke2fs I just want to know if I should use -S or not with ext4

Comment: Please post from the output of history exactly what you did

Comment: swapoff -v /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap  
lvresize /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap -L +2G  
lvresize /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home -L -4G  
lvresize /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap -L +4G  
mkswap /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap  
swapon -v /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got lucky. These commands seem to have worked!

```
mkfs.ext4 -S /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home 
e2fsck -f -y /dev/mapper/vg_curie-lv_home
```

The fsck took a couple of hours but it came back with all errors fixed and a reboot worked!